# TImage3D using too much memory in Firemonkey

Tags: image, memory, firemonkey, timage

I'm trying to create a game in Firemonkey.

I'm loading a JPG (125x182 - 15,1kb) inside a TImage3D, and running the project, checking task manager for memory in use. The program goes from 22mb aprox. to 30mb+ simply by loading this JPG.

I would like to know why and how can I change this? Because I'm about to loading too many images (since it's a game).

Edit: the code I'm using is

```
myCards[i]:=timage3d.Create(self);
myCards[i].Position.X:=1.8;
myCards[i].Position.Y:=0.45-(i/400);
myCards[i].Position.Z:=-0.44-(i/400);
myCards[i].Width:=0.625;
myCards[i].Height:=0.86;
myCards[i].RotationAngle.X:=340;
myCards[i].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('G:\CFV\cards\card_back.jpg');
myCards[i].Parent:=viewport3d1;
```

Comment: We need to see how you done this, in order to give you hints on how to do better.

Comment: I have a Firemonkey app with a Viewport, and I'm loading an image on TImage3D created dinamically with LoadFromFile. After load the image, checking task manager, the memory increases too much memory. I updated the question with the code I'm using.